# Webpack.config how to just copy the index.html to the dist folder

Tags: webpack

I am  trying to automate assets going into /dist. I have the following config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  context: __dirname + "/lib",
  entry: {
    main: [
      "./baa.ts"
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/dist",
    filename: "foo.js"
  },
  devtool: "source-map",
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader'
      },
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    // you can now require('file') instead of require('file.js')
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.json']
  }
}
```

I also want to include main.html from the directory that sits next to /lib, into the /dist folder when running webpack. How can I do this?

## UPDATE 1 2017_____________

My favourite way to do this now is to use the [`html-webpack-plugin`](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin) with a template file. Thanks to the accepted answer too! The advantage of this way is that the index file will also have the cachbusted js link added out of the box!

Comment: Please [move your answer out of the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262806/is-it-ok-for-users-to-edit-the-accepted-answer-into-their-question) and into an answer.

Answer (score 216, accepted):

**Option 1**

In your `index.js` file (i.e. webpack entry) add a require to your `index.html` via [file-loader](https://github.com/webpack/file-loader) plugin, e.g.:

`require('file-loader?name=[name].[ext]!../index.html');`

Once you build your project with webpack, `index.html` will be in the output folder.

**Option 2**

Use [html-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-webpack-plugin) to avoid having an index.html at all. Simply have webpack generate the file for you.

In this case if you want to keep your own `index.html` file as template, you may use this configuration:

```js
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  // ...
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/index.html'
    })
  ]
}
```

See the [docs](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/blob/master/docs/template-option.md) for more information.

Comment: can i somehow load it writing something in config  file itself ?

Comment: Tried the first way, and it copied the files.  But the CSS that I was copying stopped working correctly.  (I needed it external to webpack because Handsontable can't work with webpack.)

Comment: @Vaccano for CSS you shouldn't use this method. Use a style-loader and css-loader, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34039826/webpack-style-loader-vs-css-loader

Comment: the second option is really convenient :)

Comment: @codeVerine Yes, using by adding something like `{ test: /index\.html/, loader: 'file-loader', query: { name: '[name].[ext]' }` to your `loaders` array in your webpack config file, only I couldn't get webpack-dev-server to serve it, leading to, funnily enough, a 404 in requesting `/` (the root doesn't exist!).

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon adding that to my `webpack.config.js` worked perfectly for me. if you add it as a separate answer, I'll upvote it

Comment: sorry my newbie question, but how can webpack generate an index.html for me if my index.html is quite complex with a lot divs and a big structure?

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira You provide the template of the HTML you want to generate.

Comment: option 2 need to install `npm install html-webpack-plugin` and then put it `const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');` into `webpack.config.js` file.

Answer (score 76):

I will add an option to VitalyB's answer:

**Option 3**

Via npm. If you run your commands via npm, then you could add [this setup](https://github.com/kentcdodds/webpack-angular/blob/finished/step9-source-map/package.json) to your package.json (check out also the webpack.config.js there too). For developing run `npm start`, no need to copy index.html in this case because the web server will be run from the source files directory, and the bundle.js will be available from the same place (the bundle.js will live in memory only but will available as if it was located together with index.html). For production run `npm run build` and a dist folder will contain your bundle.js and index.html gets copied with good old cp-command, as you can see below:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "NODE_ENV=test karma start",
    "start": "node node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --content-base app",
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production node node_modules/.bin/webpack && cp app/index.html dist/index.html"
  }
```

**Update: Option 4**

There is a [copy-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-webpack-plugin), as described in this [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33374807/2420037)

But generally, except for the very "first" file (like index.html) and larger assets (like large images or video), include the css, html, images and so on directly in your app via `require` and webpack will include it for you (well, after you set it up correctly with loaders and possibly plugins).

Comment: Option 3 should be Option 1

Comment: I tried option 3, but hot reloading of index.html didn't work. Do you not edit your index.html very often? Serious question.

Comment: Use [ncp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ncp) instead of of cp if you'd like to support cross-OS dev environments

Answer (score 42):

You could use the [CopyWebpackPlugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-webpack-plugin). It's working just like this:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
      from: './*.html'
    }])
  ]
}
```

Comment: Now that Webpack has replaced Gulp and Grunt by not just doing bundling, but also many other build-related tasks, this solution is what I have seen in most projects. Scripts in `package.json` are only used for simple things like starting the test runner or the dev server.

Comment: This doesn't seem to automatically reload when changes are made to the original files, am I missing something?

Answer (score 16):

I would say the answer is: you can't. (or at least: you shouldn't). This is not what Webpack is supposed to do. Webpack is a bundler, and it should not be used for other tasks (in this case: copying static files is another task). You should use a tool like Grunt or Gulp to do such tasks. It is very common to integrate [Webpack as a Grunt task](https://github.com/webpack/grunt-webpack) or as a [Gulp task](http://webpack.github.io/docs/usage-with-gulp.html). They both have other tasks useful for copying files like you described, for example, [grunt-contrib-copy](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy) or [gulp-copy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-copy).

For other assets (not the `index.html`), you can just bundle them in with Webpack (that is exactly what Webpack is for).  For example, `var image = require('assets/my_image.png');`.  But I assume your `index.html` needs to not be a part of the bundle, and therefore it is not a job for the bundler.

Comment: I precisely went to webpack so I wouldn't need to use grunt or gulp. Is there any other alternative? If I need to use gulp why should I bother with webpack?

Comment: The question is upside down. Why should you use webpack if you can use grunt or gulp? They are very good task/build systems. Webpack (or browserify or r.js) are tools you can use for bundling lots of JS-files (and other resources) into one big (or multiple) javascript bundles.

You should use the correct tool for the job. And again, it is very common to run webpack, browserify or other bundlers from grunt or gulp.

Comment: how can you put an image into a js file?

Comment: There are many ways webpack can do that. You could use `file-loader` which basically just copies the file/image to the output directory and gives you the url when you requires it: `var url = require('myFile');`. As I said, a bundle can be one _or multiple_ files.

Comment: For really small assets (like a little icon or something) it is probably faster if it just bundles the image as a string in javascript. Images (and other files) can be encoded as a string (for example by using a [data uri](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/data_URIs) ). See for example [here](http://appcropolis.com/blog/web-technology/javascript-encode-images-dataurl/) for how to encode a image. There are different loaders for different kind of files in webpack, and they does this in different ways.

Comment: I might use brocolli as the parent build process

Comment: This is the right answer to me. In large/complex projects, webpack build performance is an important consideration. Various file copy plugins adds unnecessary cost to webpack, letting webpack focus on JS bundling is a better idea.

Comment: I consider stupid using other tools if a bundler (webpak) can not bundle a static file !

Comment: whatever your build script is, add a final line which does "cp ./src/index.html ./dist"

Answer (score 15):

To copy an already existing `index.html` file into the `dist` directory you can simply use the **[HtmlWebpackPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin/)** by specifying the source `index.html` as a **template**.

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  // ...
  plugins: [    
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './path/to/index.html',
    })
  ],
  // ...
};
```

The created `dist/index.html` file will be basically the same as your source file with the difference that bundled resources like **.js files are injected with `<script>` tags** by webpack. **Minification** and further options can be configured and are [documented on github](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#options).

Comment: That's much better than any kind of copy plugin.. `HtmlWebpackPlugin` is able to generate `index.html` by itself if you need. So, no need to create almost empty html page for SPA yourself.

Answer (score 14):

You can add the index directly to your entry config and using a file-loader to load it

```
module.exports = {

  entry: [
    __dirname + "/index.html",
    .. other js files here
  ],

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.html/, 
        loader: 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]', 
      },
      .. other loaders
    ]
  }

}
```

Answer (score 7):

To extend @hobbeshunter's answer if you want to take only index.html you can also use CopyPlugin,
The main motivation to use this method over using other packages is because it's a nightmare to add many packages for every single type and config it etc.
The easiest way is to use [CopyPlugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin#toType) for everything:

```
npm install copy-webpack-plugin --save-dev
```

Then

```
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new CopyPlugin([
      { from: 'static', to: 'static' },
      { from: 'index.html', to: 'index.html', toType: 'file'},
    ]),
  ],
};
```

As you can see it copy the whole static folder along with all of it's content into dist folder. 
No css or file or any other plugins needed.

While this method doesn't suit for everything, it would get the job done simply & quickly.

Answer (score 4):

This work well on Windows:

1. `npm install --save-dev copyfiles`
2. In `package.json` I have a copy task : `"copy": "copyfiles -u 1 ./app/index.html ./deploy"`

This move my index.html from the app folder into the deploy folder.

Comment: I get it works using answer there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38858718/npm-script-copy-package-json-to-dist-when-bundling/51371023#51371023

Answer (score 0):

Webpack 5 comes with [asset modules](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/) so you don't need any copy-plugins or file-loader anymore

Answer (score 0):

Ok you can copy files by npm installing copy-webpack-plugin. The version i am using here is 11.0.0.

Below the instructions tell webpack that the source js file is at ./src/index.js. The directory to build assets to is the 'dist' dir.
Then at the bottom CopyPlugin copies all html files from 'src' dir to 'dist' dir:

```
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  plugins: [
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
        {
          from: "./src/*.html",
          to({ context, absoluteFilename }) {
            return "[name][ext]";
          },
        },
      ],
    }),
  ]
};
```

Answer (score -1):

I also found it **easy** and generic enough to **put** my `index.html` **file** in `dist/` **directory** and add `<script src='main.js'></script>` to `index.html` to include my bundled webpack files. `main.js` seems to be default output name of our bundle if no other specified in *webpack's conf file*. I guess it's not good and long-term solution, but I hope it can help to understand how *webpack* works.