# Webpack style-loader vs css-loader

Tags: webpack, webpack-style-loader

I have two questions.

1) [CSS Loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-loader) and [Style Loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/style-loader) are two webpack loaders. I couldn't grasp the difference between the two. Why do I have to use two loaders when they both do the same job?

2) What is this .useable.less and .useable.css mentioned in the above Readme.md files?

Comment: See [This is how angular-cli/webpack delivers your CSS styles to the client](https://blog.angularindepth.com/this-is-how-angular-cli-webpack-delivers-your-css-styles-to-the-client-d4adf15c4975) for in-depth explanation

Answer (score 334, accepted):

The CSS loader takes a CSS file and returns the CSS with `imports` and `url(...)` resolved via webpack's `require` functionality:

> ```js
> var css = require("css!./file.css");
> // => returns css code from file.css, resolves imports and url(...)
> ```

It doesn't actually *do* anything with the returned CSS.

The style loader takes CSS and actually inserts it into the page so that the styles are active on the page.

They perform different operations, but it's often useful to chain them together, like Unix pipes. For example, if you were using [the Less CSS preprocessor](http://lesscss.org/), you could use

```js
require("style!css!less!./file.less")
```

to

1. Turn `file.less` into plain CSS with the Less loader
2. Resolve all the `imports` and `url(...)`s in the CSS with the CSS loader
3. Insert those styles into the page with the style loader

Comment: Can you please tell, what do you mena by inserting style into the page? Because I am using ExtractTextPlugin for CSS and according to what you wrote, I shouldn't be using style loader. Also, what I feel is that using style loader makes my Style getting bundled with JS until I used extract plugin. Note: I am using webpack. And after removing that style-loader, things are unchanged for me as because I just told above that I am already having my CSS in separate file created by extract plugin..

Comment: @user3241111 I think he meant this: "Adds CSS to the DOM by injecting a `<style>` tag" (this is copied from official documentation at https://github.com/webpack/style-loader)

Comment: So the idea is that webpack strips all your processed CSS and places it in the head of the document so it avoids HTTP requests for <link> tags and url style definitions?  I assume this is the point.  Things like glamor and  glamorous do this as well.  I'm pretty sure it's faster loading this way.  But I may be incorrect.

Comment: By `imports` I assume you refer to `@import` directives. By default this directive does not merge the imported CSS rules into the importer, but rather create another `GET` request. Are you saying that `css-loader` will return a merged output?

Comment: _and returns the CSS_ - it returns JS, see [This is how angular-cli/webpack delivers your CSS styles to the client](https://blog.angularindepth.com/this-is-how-angular-cli-webpack-delivers-your-css-styles-to-the-client-d4adf15c4975)

Comment: This answer doesn't explain how to configure Webpack at all. Why is it the accepted answer? @Brian Ogden has the correct answer below.

Answer (score 87):

`css-loader` reads in a css file as a string. You could replace it with `raw-loader` and get the same effect in a lot of situations. Since it just reads the file contents and nothing else, it's basically useless unless you chain it with another loader.

`style-loader` takes those styles and creates a `<style>` tag in the page's `<head>` element containing those styles.

If you look at the javascript inside `bundle.js` after using `style-loader` you'll see a comment in the generated code that says

> // style-loader: Adds some css to the DOM by adding a  tag

For example,

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- this tag was created by style-loader -->
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                background: yellow;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

That example comes from [this tutorial](https://webpack.github.io/docs/tutorials/getting-started). If you remove the `style-loader` from the pipeline by changing the line

```
require("!style-loader!css-loader!./style.css");
```

to

```
require("css-loader!./style.css");
```

you will see that the `<style>` goes away.

Comment: so when should I use `css-loader` as opposed to `raw-loader` ?

Comment: The css-loader interprets @import and url() like import/require() and will resolve them. The raw-loader only loads specified file.

Answer (score 15):

To answer the second question "What is this .useable.less and .useable.css mentioned in the above Readme.md files?", by default when a style is `require'd`, the style-loader module automatically injects a `<script>` tag into the DOM, and that tag remains in the DOM until the browser window is closed or reloaded. The style-loader module also offers a so-called "reference-counted API" that allows the developer to add styles and remove them later when they're no longer needed. The API works like this:

```
const style = require('style/loader!css!./style.css')
// The "reference counter" for this style starts at 0
// The style has not yet been injected into the DOM
style.use()  // increments counter to 1, injects a <style> tag
style.use()  // increments counter to 2
style.unuse()  // decrements counter to 1
style.unuse()  // decrements counter to 0, removes the <style> tag
```

By convention, style sheets loaded using this API have an extension ".usable.css" rather than simply ".css" as above.

Comment: This answer isn't about Webpack configuration.

Comment: @AndrewKoster I don't understand what you mean. This is an answer to the second part of the original poster's two-part question about the inner workings and file naming conventions of the style-loader module.

Comment: Sure, but as you say, there are two parts to the question. This answer (and the accepted answer) completely ignore the first part of the question, which is the more important and generally applicable part. The only answer that addresses the question of what these loaders are, and how to configure them, is Brian Ogden's answer that no one is voting for (for some reason).

Comment: I'm not using any of this weird require syntax with the crazy exclamation marks, but I still need to know how to configure these loaders in Webpack. My use case seems like a more common one than whatever you all are doing with the crazy require syntax.

Comment: @AndrewKoster Brian’s answer does not address any question I can detect.

Answer (score 12):

Let me answer 1) from your question. What is the difference between `style-loader` and `css-loader`? Or: what do they do?

- there are different incompatible module import mechanisms in Javascript
- webpack allows, rewrites and extends all well known module import mechanisms
- normally only Javascript can be imported
- with loaders, webpack also allows other files to be imported

  - if you start using that feature, that Javascript can not be used unmodified without webpack any more
- the loader decides

  - if additional files appear in the output directory (usually not)
  - what to “return”
- loaders can be chained
- the output of the last loader will be included in the bundle
- the last loader needs to return Javascript, otherwise the bundled Javascript will be faulty
- **imports which end with the `css-loader` will receive an array in Javascript**

  - I could not find proper documentation what you will receive
  - the array seems to contain one element for each CSS file processed (e.g. with CSS `@import` rules), having the file name and file content (modified) as strings
  - no extra files will end up in the output directory
  - if you use the `css-loader` alone, then you have to do something with the strings yourself or they just increase your bundle size for nothing
- **`style-loader` will wrap Javascript from `css-loader` in more Javascript**

  - it can not and does not read CSS files
  - the wrapping creates `<style>` elements with the CSS strings from `css-loader` and injects them in the DOM
  - `style-loader` can not be used alone (you get an error), because it doesn’t read files and expects `css-loader`-like Javascript as input

Comment: Upvoted , as it explains quite well how chaining (a buzzword of "pipeline") works for reverse  loading of -loaders to a final Javascript

Answer (score -2):

Webpack documentation recommends to combine style-loader with css-loader:

https://webpack.js.org/loaders/style-loader/

Comment: Which question is this trying to answer?

Comment: This is the direct answer to item `1)` in the question.

Comment: @AndrewKoster Item `1)` is the question “Why do I have to use two loaders when they both do the same job?”, which is not answered here. Note the question word “why”.