# Difference: Webpack css-loader and raw-loader

Tags: sass, webpack, loader, webpack-style-loader

So according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34039826/webpack-style-loader-vs-css-loader), `css-loader` loads file as string, resolves webpack dependency according to `require`, and `style-loader` inserts style tag into page, and in many cases, `css-loader` can be replaced by `raw-loader`.

I'm currently using:

```
loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("raw-loader!postcss-loader!sass-loader?sourceMap&" + sassIncludePaths.join(""))
```

And there are `require`s in the `.scss` files, but I don't see a problem with `raw-loader` yet. So question is:

1. What exactly is the difference between the two?
2. What might be a problem if I were to replace `css-loader` with `raw-loader` in order to reduce run time?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From my own understanding:

The main difference between `raw-loader` and `css-loader` is that the former loads in files as is, while the latter sort through webpack `require`s. Therefore, the usual use case for `css-loader` is to combine it with `style-loader`, which inserts an  tag into the page, so that it contains only the styles that are used on that page.

However, in our case, we `extractTextPlugin` them into one single file anyway, so we can just use raw-loader instead, which saves almost half the time.

Also that [`sass-loader` resolves `@import`s too](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader#imports), which is the only dependency we're using, so the setup should be doubly fine.