# Import styles for further use in the code

Tags: css-loader, webpack-3, webpack-loader

I am trying to apply a css stylesheet to my html page, as well as to obtain it as a string in javascript code (I want to show my stylesheets to users). I'm using `css-loader` and `style-loader`. Here's a snippet from webpack configuration file:

```
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          { loader: 'style-loader'},
          { loader: 'css-loader'}
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

When I use this config the styles are applied to my HTML page, but I can't obtain them as string in the code. The `console.log(style.toString())` gives me an empty object **[object Object]**. It's empty, because `Object.keys(style)` gives me `[ ]`. Here's `app.js` file:

```
const style = require('./style.css')

const test = () => {
  console.log(style.toString())
}

test()
```

If I comment out `{ loader: 'style-loader'}`, console prints my stylesheet, but the styles are not applied to the HTML page. Here's `console.log(style.toString())` output in this case:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
...
```

Any advice?

Comment: The output of the [toString function on an object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) is correct. If you want that to work you will have to override the toString function.

Comment: @fjoe, yeah, but it's an empty object in my case, because `Object.keys(style)` gives me `[  ]`

Comment: @fjoe, `toString()` method gives me the expected result if I comment out `{ loader: 'style-loader'}`.

Comment: Take a look @ [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34039826/webpack-style-loader-vs-css-loader) seems you might be missing a few things.