# Copy images in html files to output directory with webpack

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, webpack-dev-server, html-webpack-plugin

I'm trying to configure webpack so it parses my `index.html` (ideally with HTMLWebpack Plugin), so that any included image (e.g. `<object data="images/test.svg">`) is moved to my output folder, with the folder path remaining the same. Ultimately, running webpack-dev-server should render a page that displays my images.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27639005/how-to-copy-static-files-to-build-directory-with-webpack) question is somewhat related, but doesn't quite match my own problem.

#### What I tried to do:

As you can see from my config file, [I tried using the html-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-loader). Without the `exclude: /index\.html$/` it gives me an error. My guess is that the HTMLWebpack Plugin and the html-loader don't get along. Excluding index.html defeats the purpose of html-loader. File-loader doesn't recognize images that aren't included using `require(image)`.

What is currently happening: Everything runs fine, but there's no images folder, nor any image in `/dist/`.

My current **webpack.config.js**

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var HTMLWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: __dirname + '/app/index.html',
  filename: 'index.html',
  inject: 'body'
});

module.exports = {
  entry: './app/index.js',

  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    publicPath: '/dist',
    filename: 'index_bundle.js'
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
    { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader'},
    { test: /\.svg$/, loader: 'file-loader' },
    { test: /\.html$/, exclude: /index\.html$/, loader: 'html-loader'}
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    HTMLWebpackPluginConfig
  ]
}
```

Example **index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="demoSpace"><object data="images/test.svg"  type="image/svg+xml"></object></div>
    <div id="test"></div> 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js">      
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

My take on what I see [in the html-loader documentation](https://github.com/webpack/html-loader) is that it will default to automatically `require`ing what it finds in "img" tags.  Since you're dealing with an "object" tag you probably want to focus on the **tag-attribute processing** feature discussed:

> You can specify which tag-attribute combination should be processed by
>   this loader via the query parameter attrs. Pass an array or a
>   space-separated list of : combinations. (Default:
>   attrs=img:src)