# Include a JSON file as Webpack output, but not part of bundle.js

Tags: node.js, html, reactjs, npm, webpack

I have a webpack app that I'd like to read a json file in **at runtime**.

After webpack packages the application, I'd like the json file to be excluded from the bundle.js but still in the package folder. How can I do this?

Comment: Same as you would use an image : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27639005/how-to-copy-static-files-to-build-directory-with-webpack with file-loader.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use [copy-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin)

Pretty simply moves files from one location to another

You moved the json file into the destination package by passing it an object:

`{ from: 'source', to: 'dest' }`

Checkout [the repo](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin) for usage examples

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`file-loader`](https://github.com/webpack/file-loader) which will let you specify an output file. Not the cleanest, since webpack really really wants to bundle everything, but it works.

```
require('file?name=../newfile.json!/somefolder/original.json');
```

The above will create newfile.json a directory above your webpack output folder. (Folder change for illustration purposes; not required.)

If you want to re-require the json*, mark it as an external dependency in the webpack config and use `require('../newfile.json').

*I'd suggest using a regular ajax call to pull the json in though. That way it's clear that the json is an external and you won't have to go through webpack's ajax system.

Comment: If I use var jsonData = require('../pageJSON/page.json');
and console log it, I get /aac68c8f2642e163fd998c4c012d0d14.json

Comment: The `name` part is the important bit. That tells webpack what to name the output file. (Otherwise it's included in the bundle like a normal loader's output.)

Comment: The issue is that I want the var jsonData to be the json object, but it's the path apparently.

Comment: Ah! 1. Output it to it's own file using the method above. 2. Note it as an 'external' resource in your webpack config. 3. `require` the _new_ file.

Comment: So the json is located in /pageJSON/config.json.
In my externals, do I say 'config.json' : '/pageJSON/config.json' ?
and then var jsonData = require('file?config.json!config.json'); ?

Comment: Why in a directory above the webpack output? I want the json in the webpack output so when it's deployed, I can edit the json file without having to repackage everything