# How to treat require/import as a value and not dependency

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, bundler, tree-shaking

**Case I:**
I have a file called `data.json`

```
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2,
  ...
}
```

Which I imported/required in `index.js` as shown below

```
import data from './data.json';

console.log(data["a"]);
```

Everything works fine but the whole data.json is dumped into index.js when bundled with webpack hence file size increased with property values I don't need.

**Case II:**
However, if I do the following in `index.js`

```
const a = {
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2,
  ...
}

console.log(data["a"]);
```

Everything is fine (The value 1 get logged) and no unnecessary properties of the json variable a were dumped. I think webpack's Tree Shaking is working here (I'm not sure)

**My Question:**
How can I achieve case II (no unnecessary properties) by requiring/importing the file like it's done in case I?

I was thinking if there's a way to treat the content of require as a value and not a dependency so webpack or any other bundler doesn't include it in the bundled file.

PS: I'm bundling for WEB

Comment: Don't use json, and just export an object..  `export const data = {a:1, b:2}`   ps.  case II is not JSON.

Comment: Thank you @Keith, that worked! I exported as you said (as js file) then 

```import {data} from './data.js';```

Would you like to make this an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Sorry, didn't read properly.

[Include a JSON file as Webpack output, but not part of bundle.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38959329/include-a-json-file-as-webpack-output-but-not-part-of-bundle-js)

I think this is what you are looking for.

<strike>Dylan's solution is very nice too, but I prefer simply:
Edited out code..</strike>

Comment: This isn't about loading a JSON file, OP knows how to do that. Please re-read the question.

Comment: Alright, then it's a possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38959329/include-a-json-file-as-webpack-output-but-not-part-of-bundle-js

Comment: Thanks ChrisG and everyone else. @keith's comment worked out for me