# Using path.resolve from webpack bundle file

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs, webpack

I have a server file that is created from `src/server/index.js` and bundled to and run from `build/server.js`. When importing modules everything works, but I am having and issue where a folder can't be found when using `path.resolve`.

I am doing something like this but once the server file is bundled the following path cannot be found. My guess is because I am not importing it and therefore it is never bundled.

`path.resolve(__dirname, 'server/email_templates')`

Is there a way to make sure that my application can find this folder after being bundled ?

I have tried to adding resolve object to my webpack config, but that seems to only work for requiring and importing modules, not using the `path` module. Here's my webpack config object.

```
entry: {
    app: path.join(__dirname, 'src/server/index.js')
},

output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
    publicPath: '/assets/',
    filename: 'server.js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
},

target: 'node',

module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /(\.js|\.jsx)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel',
            query: {
                presets: [
                    'react',
                    'node6',
                    'stage-0'
                ]
            }
        },
        serverUrlLoader,
        serverStyleLoader,
    ],
},
```

Folder Structure

```
src
|_____server
      |-index.js - entry point for bundle
      |_____email_templates
build
|_____server.bundle.js
```

Comment: can you show your folder structure?

Comment: i added folder structure @RafiUdDaulaRefat

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to copy `src/server/email_templates` to `build`, in which case [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33374807/893780) might be of help.

Comment: thanks @robertklep i was wondering if there was a way to access the correct path without copying the folder, but that may be the way to go.

Comment: @realseanp you could use `path.join(__dirname, '../src/server/email_templates')`, but that would only work from `build/`

Comment: as said above path.join(__dirname, '../src/server/email_templates') would help you.