# WebPack HTML and File Loader with programmatic img src

Tags: html, webpack, vue.js, webpack-file-loader, webpack-html-loader

I'm using WebPack 2 and we're trying to specify an image name programmatically with Vue, and bind it in the HTML. Since the image name and path isn't bound until run-time, HTML and File Loader doesn't rewrite the url.

Is there a way to tell HTML/File loader that "any of [these files] might be needed at runtime" without just putting them in a list for the file copy plugin?

```
<img :src="`~assets/images/tmp-iconic/${random}.jpg`">
```

It gets passed through to the client as written, and then Vue binds ${random} at runtime, and of course the image isn't in the application.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you will want to do is use this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33374807/379650 and copy the image folder over to your build.

Comment: Using the copy file plugin was something I was specifically trying to avoid. I know I can fall back to that though. Maybe a golden opportunity for a missing loader, to automatically copy the content of a folder when it can detect a path but not resolve a file.