# Webpack build not including resources/json files

Tags: angular, npm, webpack, localization, webpack-2

My Webpack build is not including my resources folder into the dist build, which is causing my translation files to never get picked up and therefore no translation is taking place...

**File structure:**

```
dist
   //I need my json files from src/resources here
src
  app // holds all components
  resources 
      locale-en-us.json
      locale-fr-fr-json
      locale-ru-ru.json
      locale-zh-cn-json
webpack
    webpack.common.js
    webpack.server.js
```

**weback.server.js:**

```
const { root } = require('./helpers');

const { AotPlugin } = require('@ngtools/webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: root('./src/main.server.ts'),
    output: {
         filename: 'server.js'
     },
    target: 'node'
};
```

**webpack.common.js**

```
 const { root } = require('./helpers');

 const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

 /**
   * This is a common webpack config which is the base for all builds
 */
  module.exports = {
      devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
      resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
       },
      output: {
       path: root('dist')
       },
      module: {
        rules: [
         { test: /\.ts$/, loader: '@ngtools/webpack' },      
         { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'raw-loader' },
         { test: /\.less$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallback: 'style-loader', use: 'css-loader?sourceMap!less-loader?sourceMap' }) },
         { test: /\.scss$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallback: 'style-loader', use: 'css-loader?sourceMap!sass-loader?sourceMap' }) },
         { test: /\.css$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallback: 'style-loader', use: 'css-loader?sourceMap' }) },
         { test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192&minetype=application/font-woff&name=fonts/[name].[hash].[ext]' },
         { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: 'file-loader?name=fonts/[name].[hash].[ext]' },
         { test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=4096&name=images/[name].[hash].[ext]' }
        ]
     },
     plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css')
     ]
 };
```

I'm using Webpack v2.5.1. Anybody know what I'm missing here? It's my understanding I should not have to include any json loader in Webpack version 2.0+

Do I need to import my files from the resources folder somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Webpack only considers the files explicitly imported/required by your code.

If you just want to move some files into your build directory, have a look to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33374807/2902821) on how to set up [copy-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/kevlened/copy-webpack-plugin).

Comment: Thanks for the help!