# Few confusions and queries on webpack workflow on React

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm getting started with `React 15`. After going through tutorial and reading a few articles, I've come up with a few questions about the workflow. Here's how my index and webpack files look.

**`index.html`**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Lugmety.com | The fastest, Most convenient way to order from the finest restaurants in Jeddah.</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/images/lugmety-favicon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="app"></div>

<script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assetsjs/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/scripts.js"></script>
<script src="/bundle.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**`webpack.config.js`**

```
let webpack = require("webpack");
let path = require("path");

let DIST_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname,"dist");
let SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname,"src");

let config = {
    entry: SRC_DIR + "/index.js",
    output: {
        path: DIST_DIR + "/",
        filename: "bundle.js",
        publicPath: "/"
    },
    module:{
        loaders:[
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.js?/,
                include: SRC_DIR,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                query: {
                    presets:["react", "es2015", "stage-2"]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};

module.exports = config;
```

Here is my `index.html` file.

1. Does the compilation compile scripts like `jquery.js`, `bootstrap.js` and custom scripts for eg. `script.js` and include it in the compiled `bundle.js`?
2. In development, my `images` are located in `src/assets/img/`. I can't see the compiler copying assets into the dist folder.
3. From where do I set the relative paths for the CSS and JS files in index.html and the images within components? For eg. `<img src="/assets/img/image.jpg">` OR `<img src="/src/assets/img/image.jpg">`

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: If you are just learning, I'd recommend following this tutorial(actually, its a book) on React.  https://survivejs.com/webpack/introduction/

Webpack is a complex but awesome tool, give it a couple of days to sink in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No in your case it won't be included in bundle.js because you are not using npm modules for bootstrap and jquery. You can try this way to include in your dev dependencies :

   npm i -D  bootstrap jquery
2. You don't need to copy assets to the dist folder. Webpack is a module bundler and everything you reference in your files will be included. You just need to specify a loader for that.For your  reference :

   [How to copy static files to build directory with Webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27639005/how-to-copy-static-files-to-build-directory-with-webpack)
3. I don't really get the question but ofcourse you will set the path for css in the index.html for css you just have to import it with relative path. For example :

   import App from './App'

Comment: Thanks, that's good info. What about my images? Does webpack bundle images into `bundle.js` too?

Comment: No webpack only bundles the js files.It just load the type of file mentioned in loaders example svg,css,etc . However you can leverage the build system to create sprite image for all the images or concatenate and uglify all your css .