# Handling config files with webpack

Tags: webpack, electron, webpack-2

I have an electron app that I'm building with webpack 2. I have a config file that I'm including like a normal webpack resource:

```
config.js:

export default {
    config1: 1,
    config2: 2
}

main.js:

import config from '../some/path/config';
console.log(config.config1);
```

The config file code ends up in my `bundle.js` file as you would expect. The problem is that the point of config files is that you can change them after deployment. This set up requires me to re-webpackify everything if I want config file changes to take effect.

#### Update 1:

I thought [file-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader) might be the answer but the problem is that file loader replaces `require` statement with a path to a file, not the file content itself.

#### Update 2:

At the suggestion of @sancelot, I tried making it a separate entry point and output in my webpack config file.

```
entry: {
    main: ['babel-polyfill', path.join(__dirname, '../app/main.js')],
    config: [path.join(__dirname, '../app/config.js')]
},

output: {
    path: `${__dirname}/../build/`,
    publicPath: `${__dirname}/../build/`,
    filename: '../build/[name].bundle.js'
}
```

which did create a separate `config.bundle.js` file but `main.bundle.js` still contained its own copy of the config file internally and basically ignored `config.bundle.js`. For the sake of completeness, I here is the entire webpack config file:

```
import webpack from 'webpack';
import path from 'path';


export default {
    devtool: 'source-map',

    target: 'electron-main',

    entry: {
        main: ['babel-polyfill', path.join(__dirname, '../app/main.js')],
        config: [path.join(__dirname, '../app/config.js')]
    },

    output: {
        path: `${__dirname}/../build/`,
        publicPath: `${__dirname}/../build/`,
        filename: '../build/[name].bundle.js'
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        cacheDirectory: true
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /index.html/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: 'index.html'
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production'),
            'process.env.devMode': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
            'process.env.prodMode': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
            'process.env.DEBUG_PROD': JSON.stringify(process.env.DEBUG_PROD || 'false')
        })
    ],

    node: {
        __dirname: false,
        __filename: false
    },
}
```

Comment: I think this should help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27639005/how-to-copy-static-files-to-build-directory-with-webpack

Comment: Yeah, I actually went down that path without much luck. I updated my post to reflect that info.

Comment: What do you mean by changing after deployment? Do you mean that the config files should have deployment-specific values? Like API secrets and so? If so, checkout `dotenv`

Comment: @Esben, for example, let's say the config file contains the logging level (debug, info, warn, or error). At some point after deployment to production I want to change the logging level from debug to warn. I can't do that without recompiling. I guess environment variables are an option, but I feel like config files are easier to work with.

Answer (score 2):

you have to add an entry in  your webpack config

```
{
  entry: {
    app: './src/app.js',
    config: './src/config.js'
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: __dirname + '/dist'
  }
 }
```

https://webpack.js.org/concepts/output/

Comment: I tried that and it does create a separate config file, but it's also still adding the config data directly into my `bundle.js` and that's the config data it's using at run time. How do you tell it to grab the config data from the separate `config.js` file?

Comment: I would need the complete webpack.config.js file

Comment: I went ahead and posted the entire webpack config file

Comment: I have had a look and finally found it was better to use code splitting , I think this is what you need . read this please : https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html#split-app-and-vendor-code

Comment: I think your suggestion is correct, thank you. However there appears to be some kind of issue between the `electron` main process and `CommonsChunkPlugin` that prevents the app from working. I created another post about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45759756/commonschunkplugin-doesnt-work-with-electron

Answer (score 0):

For this case, I'd suggest [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv)

For client-side applications (that run in browsers), I'd suggest [envify](https://github.com/hughsk/envify).

Both suggestions have easy to follow setup guides.

Comment: Question was about handling config at runtime, your answer is about build time.