# How to copy files from public into dist?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a public folder that looks as follows:
[image]

After building the project with

```
"prod": "npm run mlbuild | npm run build"
```

the dist folder looks as following:

[image]

But I am missing `config.json`, `favicon.ico` and `keycloak.json`.

How to take these files into `dist` folder during the `build`?

I tried:

```
  {
    test: /\.(json)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
    use: [{
      loader: 'file-loader',
      options: {
        name: '[name].[ext]'
      }
    }]
  }
```

But I think, I have to mention the folder.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy static files to build directory with Webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27639005/how-to-copy-static-files-to-build-directory-with-webpack)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can just setup the plugin [copy-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin) to copy those files, adding this to your webpack.config.js:

```
plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([{ from: 'public' }])
  ]
```

and the following require: `const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')`

Another solution, if you don't want to do it using webpack, is to use a package to copy those files to the dist folder after the build, adding the following script:

```
"postprod": "cpx \"public/*\" dist"
```

and add the package `cpx` to your list of devDependencies, running `npm install cpx --save-dev`.
Because you added the `post` prefix to `postprod`, everytime you run the `prod` script, npm will automatically run `postprod` after it, and therefore, will copy all files inside the public folder to the dist folder. You can read more about npm scripts [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts)