# Typescript: How to include imported images in the output directory?

Tags: typescript

**typings/index.d.ts**

```
declare module "*.svg";
declare module "*.png";
declare module "*.jpg";
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "declaration": true,
        "outDir": "./dist"
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*", "typings/index.d.ts"]
}
```

When I run `build`, it doesn't include the imported images.

Comment: TypeScript won't do this. This is a job for a bundler like `webpack` or `parcel`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy static files to build directory with Webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27639005/how-to-copy-static-files-to-build-directory-with-webpack)

Comment: How I can do this in Nodejs ?

Answer (score 13):

The compiler won't include those files.

If you're using NPM for instance, you can copy them to your build directory by using a tool like [copyfiles](https://www.npmjs.com/package/copyfiles). Your build script would look something like that:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "tsc && copyfiles *.png build/images"
}
```

There are multiple ways to do this though, like using [webpack](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/quick/browser.html).

Comment: I realized I need a bundler for me to include assets. So, I used webpack for me to fix this.