# React import images from public folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to get static images fro my public directory but is not being found. I'm not using CRA, so maybe is some configuration with Webpack that I'm missing. Using file-loader module and importing the image works on Dev Mode, but doesn't work in for my production server specification

My Project structure:

```
\public
   \static
      \images
         image.png
\src
   \component
      component.js
...
package.json
webpack.common.js
webpack.dev.js
webpack.prod.js
```

On component.js, I want to get image.jpg on static/images folder like this:

```
  <img src='/static/images/image.png'></img>
```

But I'm getting a 404 not found.

My webpack.commom.js:

```
const CleanWebPackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin')
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        main: './src/index.js'
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].[hash].js',
        path: path.resolve('./dist'),
        publicPath: "/"
    },
    module:{
        rules:[
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: ['/node_modules'],
                use: [{ loader: 'babel-loader'}],
            },
            {
                test: /\.s?(a|c)ss$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'style-loader'
                }, {
                    loader: 'css-loader'
                },{
                    loader: 'sass-loader'
                }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/,
                use: [
                  {
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {},
                  },
                ],
              },

        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            template: 'index.html'
        }),
        new CleanWebPackPlugin(),
    ],
}
```

And the Dev version:

```
module.exports = merge(common, {
    mode: 'development',
    devServer: {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 3000,
        open: true,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        publicPath: "/",
    }
})
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A couple things: You are setting 'src' as '/static/image.png' but according to your project structure it should be '/static/images/image.png'. Was that a typo? What does your 'dist/' folder look like after running a production build? Does it include that image file?

Comment: It was a typo error, indeed. In the production dist/ fold appears the image just if I import by the loader webpack plugin, which is not a good option for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `file-loader` as webpack plugin, which does not work in the way of "just mirroring the directory structure of `public` to dist". You can find the documentation for that plugin here: https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/

Basically, what the plugin does is, if you import an image file (actually programatically importing it, not just using a string reference to its path), the file is copied to your dist directory, potentially renamed and than in your compiled source code the proper file name is inserted.

So in your case, if you want to solve your problem using `file-loader`, you would reference the image file like

```
// Relative path to image file from js file
import imageFile from './assets/image.png';

// ...
const component = props => <img src={imageFile}></img>;
```

If you want to use the approach of actually just mirroring a `public`-directory to the dist directory, you need to use an additional webpack-plugin for that (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/33374807/2692307)

By the way, I assume it works in dev-mode because you are setting '/' as public path, so the development server just serves everything in the root directory as well. That is something different than copying the files to dist however as you are trying to achieve.

Comment: The import using file-loader works, but I need to access the source directly from the public path like   <img src='/static/images/image.png'></img>.
**But the dev server doesn't find the sources**. This is the big problem. 

**The copy-webpack-plugin solved my problem**, but not sure why.

Thank you, anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you want to display such image more than once. In that case, is annoying to keep writing something like '%PUBLIC_URL%/img/static/images/image.png' or {process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/img/static/images/image.png'} two, three or more times within your jsx code. Basically, without a plugin is imposible to import images from the public folder if your app is rooted in the src folder. However I did find a solution for me and was quite simple in fact. It was something like this:

```
import React from 'react'

var path = process.env.PUBLIC_URL;
var image = "/img/static/images/image.png";
```

and then, within jsx code:

```
<img src={path + image}/>
```

it worked for me, hope this is helpful for anyone! :D

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this help but I'm will give it a try

Try to add public path to your dist folder also something like this

```
output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "/dist"),
        filename: "[name].js",
        publicPath: "/dist/"
    },
```