# CopyWebpackPlugin isn't copying static files to output directory

Tags: vue.js, webpack, html-webpack-plugin, webpack-cli

My files show as being emitted but they are not actually being copied to dist folder.

Excerpt of compilation log:

> ```
>   Version: webpack 4.15.1         Time: 1824ms        Built at: 01/29/2020 3:51:51 PM
>                          Asset      Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
>                        main.js   116 KiB       0  [emitted]         main
>                   CSS/main.css  76 bytes          [emitted]               Images/Uplink_Logo_Horiz.jpg   651 KiB          [emitted]  [big]  
>               CSS/adminlte.css   708 KiB          [emitted]  [big]  
>                     index.html   6.7 KiB          [emitted]
> ```

And my webpack config plugin looks like this:

> ```
> plugins: [
>     new CopyWebpackPlugin([
>         {
>             from: './Images/**',
>             to: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
>             logLevel: 'trace'
>         },
>         {
>             from: './CSS/**',
>             to: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
>             logLevel: 'trace'
>         }
>     ]),
>     new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
>         template: './src/index.html'
>     })
> ],
> ```

I tried changing the order of CopyWebpackPlugin & HtmlWebpackPlugin to no luck. Did you do any other thing to solve this other than just changing the order.

Versions:

> "vue": "^2.6.11", "webpack": "^4.15.0", "webpack-cli": "^3.0.8",
>   "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.1.1", "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",

**Updated Image:**
Full project structure:

[image]

Comment: Can you post your full project structure please? Can't help without knowing where everything lives in your project.

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda Added project structure.

Comment: Hmm okay, can you open the Images directory as well? Are your images nested in sub-directories under Images at all?

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda No they are not.

Comment: Your config snippet looks good. My only thought would be are you manually excluding images in one of your config files? Are you using a webpack file loader of any kind?

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda Nope i am not using any webpack loader file. I initially though it was the issue with clean-webpack-plugin, so i took it out. But the issue still persists

Comment: Another idea would be to change your `from` source to copy the entire directory instead of each individual file. Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33374807/5535040

Answer (score -1):

Found out the issue. The static files were not included in the VS project. Once I included them it started working. Thanks, for the help :)