# Images aren't sharing between bundles

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have issue with sharing images between two bundles. I import image in one bundle and then import that built bundle into another app. I've created the [repo](https://github.com/ksmolniy/webpack-sharing-image-between-bundles) with example of what I got and what I need for more clarity.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your question - can you post the focus parts of your code here?  I think it will produce better feedback.

Comment: I've looked at the repo. You're importing a jpg file and then returning the import results as a module.exports and in your main index.js you're executing it as a function..... What's the logic behind that?

Comment: @Tschallacka In the original app, it's a react component that imports the image and then it's imported in an app. And it can be many components

Comment: @ksmolniy but why `console.log(childModule());` you're executing a jpg file as a function? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Tschallacka I've added more clarity to code. Now child module creates an image element with my picture and the main package append it into the document. I need to webpack found image dependencies in the child module and add it to the main build folder

Comment: Ahh, now I understand. Does this answer help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27639005/how-to-copy-static-files-to-build-directory-with-webpack

Comment: @Tschallacka little bit. I added Copy Webpack Plugin and it fixed my problem enough