# How to access using php a json file located in the src folder in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs

How to access using php a json file located in the src folder in ReactJS

[my data.json file in my Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtYBe.png)

After building I can't access to the data.json file

The files look like this
[build folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9MeP.png)

Comment: Where is the PHP code located

Comment: located on the same host as my React project

Comment: Which folder, I dont think I see it in the directories you show

Comment: in the Puplic folder "/Backend/index.php"

Comment: When you say you cannot access the json file, are you getting an error that you can show us? I might expect that your server is configured to protect the src folder

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you don't. The src folder contains the source code for the React app. It isn't something that should be directly used in production.

If you are using Webpack to build your production version then, [as per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33374807/19068) you can use the [CopyWebpackPlugin plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin/) to copy the JSON file to your build directory and deploy it with the rest of the application.

That should give you a predictable file path (if the PHP is on the same system as the server for the React frontend) or URL (otherwise) that you can request with [`file_get_contents`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and then parse with [`json_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).